# Does "ditto driver" mean a specific driver name?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I got an email today that contained the following sentence:

> a proprietary dongle with ditto driver

What does *ditto* mean in this case? Some kind of specific standard? Or does it mean "proprietary"?

I tried to find some information about *ditto* but I couldn't.

Comment: It **might** mean "a proprietary dongle with **a proprietary** driver", because "ditto" means _the same as above_. And "ditto" is easier to type than "proprietary".

Comment: The meaning is clear, but it strikes me as a very casual/non-standard usage. I wouldn't expect to find it in any remotely "formal" context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Ditto* normally means ‘the same’, so I would guess the phrase means ‘a proprietary dongle with a proprietary driver’.

Answer (score -1):

dit·to [díttō]
interjection 
 same here: used instead of repeating something that has just been said to indicate that the same thing applies to you (informal)

adverb 
 the same thing applies elsewhere: indicating that whatever has just been said about one person or thing applies equally to somebody or something else 
The car will need to be cleaned; ditto the children.

noun (plural dit·tos) 
 symbols representing repeated matter: a pair of symbols (") that together represent matter that is repeated directly from what appears above them but that is unstated

transitive verb (past dit·toed, past participle dit·toed, present participle dit·to·ing, 3rd person present singular dit·tos) 
 repeat something: to repeat or imitate something that somebody else has said or done

[Early 17th century. Via a Tuscan dialect variant of Italian detto “said,” from the Latin past participle dictus . Originally used to avoid repeating the name of a month.]